# Manipulating big number in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I developed a small script to simulate the Syracuse conjecture in Powershell.

I'm using it with very large number and i'm studying the result in an Excel graph but powershell keeps formatting my number when they are too big :

This is the result i get for the firsts iterations

```
1.60827282342995E+40 
8.04136411714975E+39 
4.02068205857487E+39 
2.01034102928744E+39 
1.00517051464372E+39 
5.02585257321859E+38
```

I would like to have the result without the formatting "E+XX", is there any way to log the entire number to analyse its composition ?

EDIT : The script i wrote :

```
Remove-Item "E:\syracuse.txt"

$Logfile = "E:\syracuse.txt"
Function LogWrite
{
Param ([string]$logstring)

Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

$chiffre1 = 0
$chiffre2 = 0


$chiffre1 = read-host "chiffre"

write-host Sequence Initiale $chiffre1

$val = 0

while ($val -ne 32132135464664546546545645656454665412321321231321654657987465432132154)

{


$val++

if ([bool]!($chiffre1%2))

{
   Write-Host "Pair"
   $chiffre2=($chiffre1)/2 
   write-host $chiffre2
   LogWrite $chiffre2,$val

}
Else
{
   Write-Host "Impair"
   $chiffre2 = $chiffre1*3+1
   write-host $chiffre2
   LogWrite $chiffre2,$val

}

if ([bool]!($chiffre2%2))

{
   Write-Host "Pair"
   $chiffre1=($chiffre2)/2 
   write-host $chiffre1
   LogWrite $chiffre1,$val
}
Else
{
   Write-Host "Impair"
   $chiffre1 = $chiffre2*3+1
   write-host $chiffre1
   LogWrite $chiffre1,$val

}

}
```

$val has an arbitrary value

I have Powershell 2.0 only, i'm updating to Powershell v3 right now.

Edit2 : It's very weird now.
In the ISE, the script doesn't work, the number is an odd everytime.

I think i managed to find a little solution with the help of bigInt
For some reason it doesn't work on ISE but it works on the Powershell v3 cmd.

I modified my LogWrite line for :

```
LogWrite ([bigint]$chiffre1),$val
```

or

```
LogWrite ([bigint]$chiffre2),$val
```

My log now has the good formatting !

Comment: Can you show us the script?

Comment: @PetSerAl Syracuse conjecture involves only integers. Still, 64 bits won't do. `System.Numerics.BigInteger` might be an option

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Given the formatting, OP definitely use `System.Double`, which can not event store `18014398509481985` value.

Comment: @PetSerAl `1e40 + 60827282342995e26`, not a double, same formatting as OP

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `(1e40 + 60827282342995e26).GetType().Name` print `Double` for me.

Comment: `32132135464664546546545645656454665412321321231321654657987465432132154 -eq 32132135464664544769808789237349202604198063872858960555186100570685440` If you expect `False` from this comparison, then you will be surprised.

Answer (score 9):

In PowerShell 3.0+ you can use the [`System.Numerics.BigInteger` data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) to represent arbitrarily large integer values:

```
PS C:\> 1e15
1E+15
PS C:\> 1e15 -as [System.Numerics.BigInteger]
1000000000000000
```

There's even a builtin type accelerator for it (`[bigint]`):

```
PS C:\> [bigint]1e15
1000000000000000
```

Comment: Can't this be modified using a new `format.ps1xml` following the steps [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847831.aspx)

Comment: @user4317867 It is not about format. `System.Double` type, which used by PowerShell by default simply can not store big numbers with enough precision.

Comment: How come this doesn't work when iterating through a big integer range with a foreach loop?